# Key type in Cache Configuration for table without key?

Tags: ignite

What will be the Key type in Cache Configuration if the database table that I'm loading cache from has no key, but in fact, also has duplicate rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an artificial key in this case. If you assign, for example, a unique integer key to each row, then you'll be able to store them in Ignite cache. It can be done during data loading.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Could you maybe give a sample code snippet?

Comment: @PragyaMalik well, I don't really know, what code snippet to give you. I suggested you a pretty simple idea, when you make a cache with a key of type `Integer` and put data with incrementing keys, like this: `cache.put(i++, row)`. That's basically it.